# How to integrate code into application in python

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

This is my application code:

```
#GUI
from tkinter import *
#Create the window
root = Tk()
#Modify root window
root.title("Simple Bot")
root.geometry("500x400")
#Kick off the event loop
root.mainloop()
```

This is the bot code:

```
botName = input("Bot: Hello User, my name is ______ please name me: ");
botName = botName + ": ";
print(botName + "Thankyou for naming me.");
firstName = input(botName + "What is your name? ");
print(botName + "Hello, " + firstName);
favourite =  input(botName + "Tell us what you like doing the most? ");
print(botName + "Nice, I like to do that as well.");
print(botName + "If you have any Questions just ask.");
```

How do I get the bot code to work inside of the application I have created, and what other code do I have to add for the bot code to work in the application.

P.S. I am new to python and trying out different things.

Comment: May be you wish to use `Entry` for input and `massageBox` for print in your Tkinter root window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a simple example to begin, try this:

```
from  Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

root = Tk()

root.title("Simple Bot")
root.geometry("500x80")

def msg(ev=None):
   tkMessageBox.showinfo("Message", v.get() + " Thank you for naming me.")


root.bind('<Return>', msg)

L = Label(root, text="Bot: Hello User, my name is ______ please name me: ", font=("Helvetica", 14)) 

v = StringVar()
E = Entry(root, textvariable=v, font=("Helvetica", 16))
      
L.pack()
E.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

root.mainloop()
```

print is replaced with `tkMessageBox` and input with `Entry`

Use `v.get()` to get text from `Entry` and `v.set()` to change its content.

Comment: I put in the code you have put up and it returned an error saying: No module named 'Tkinter'

Comment: try tkinter, i guess you are using python3.

Comment: I have downloaded pycharm. Is that python 3? What is a module?

Comment: No. PyCharm is a smart code editor.The problem is that `Tkinter` was renamed to `tkinter`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two python files(e.g - modules). First file - gui, second - some logic part(firstname, favourite things and etc)
You should create some text area(for example - label or message box) where you will display information.

You can start your application, after that you start your bot code(import it, i think), where you get information. Then you put your information in text area.Or you can firstly start bot code, and after that start application code, where you put firstname and favourite in label or text.

For example in code below we put bot name in Text Area.
bot.py - it's your bot code module.

```
from tkinter import *
import bot

#Create the window
root = Tk()
#Modify root window
root.title("Simple Bot")
root.geometry("500x400")

text = Text(root)

text.insert(INSERT, bot.firstName)
text.pack()

#Kick off the event loop
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these are two different .py files, you can simply use the import statement if all you need are the variables.

```
import bot_code
```

If you'd like to use the entire chuck of code at once inside of your application, you could put it in a function like so:

```
def bot():
    botName = input("Bot: Hello User, my name is ______ please name me: ");
    botName = botName + ": ";
    print(botName + "Thankyou for naming me.");
    firstName = input(botName + "What is your name? ");
    print(botName + "Hello, " + firstName);
    favourite =  input(botName + "Tell us what you like doing the most? ");
    print(botName + "Nice, I like to do that as well.");
    print(botName + "If you have any Questions just ask.");
```

and then just import as stated above. Now you can call the function inside of your application and all the code will run.

```
import bot_code
bot() # This makes your botcode run
```

*I am assuming your bot code is in a file 'bot_code.py'*